# Where is missing searchbar left-hand panel in MS Access 2007?

Tags: gui, microsoft-access-2007, ribbon

I recently opened a reporting database in Access 2007 that appears to be missing a search bar in the database objects panel.  I'm familiar with MS Access, but not the new ribbon functionality.  How do I turn the search bar back on?

[image] [image]

I messed with the menus in the little down triangle there and the settings are the same but one has a search bar and the other does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Office `Globe->Access` Options
2. In the `Access Options` window left hand panel clicked `Current Database`
3. In the right column scrolled down to `Navigation` and clicked `Navigation Options`
4. Checked off `Show Search Bar`
5. Clicked ok a series of times and reopened the database.